# SWTableView swipe cell issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, swtableviewcell

I'm using SWTableView for swipe left to give to the user more options, i added 4 elements and when i close the cell back , not all the cell return back to the place.
Please help[image: ![See below image the swipe back not close all the buttons]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTfdW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to set the cell's delegate? As described in the README?

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";

    MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = (MyCustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
                                                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.leftUtilityButtons = [self leftButtons];
    cell.rightUtilityButtons = [self rightButtons];
    cell.delegate = self;

    cell.customLabel.text = @"Some Text";
    cell.customImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyAwesomeTableCellImage"];
    [cell setCellHeight:cell.frame.size.height];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Add this  [self hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:NO]; inside of SWTableViewCell.m at initialising place

Comment: if thats not work, Add this on cellForRowAtIndexPath    if (!self.isThumbnailView) {
for (SWTableViewCell *cell in [tableview visibleCells]) {
[cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
}
}